# Hibernate connection error Could not fetch data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am using JAVA+Hibernate +Spring+vaadin for my project
i am fetching some data via hibernate and it is showing this error

```
myProject.services.MyServicesException: myProject.Dao.MyDaoException: Exception while getting all data details
    at myProject.services.MyServicesImpl.getAlldata(MyServicesImpl.java:57)
    at myProject.ui.main.NewInputFormView$7$4.buttonClick(NewInputFormView.java:840)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:978)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:275)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1405)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: myProject.Dao.MyDaoException: Exception while getting all data details
    at myProject.Dao.MyProcDaoImpl.getAlldata(MyProcDaoImpl.java:113)
    at myProject.services.MyServicesImpl.getAlldata(MyServicesImpl.java:53)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1661)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at myProject.Dao.MyProcDaoImpl.getAlldata(MyProcDaoImpl.java:103)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 61 more
```

Can anyone help me with this

my cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>


    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://10.51.33.60:5432/ddddd</property>
    <property name="connection.username">abc</property>
    <property name="connection.password">abc</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="in/abc/def/Dao/ServiceVO.hbm.xml" />


</session-factory>
```

i have not yet mentioned any maximum connections

Comment: That is the root cause `FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`. looks like your database has not enough connections.

Comment: How can i increase connections?

Comment: Do you need so much connections? If not i think you should close the connections after use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure [connection pooling](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/):

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://10.51.33.60:5432/ddddd</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">abc</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<!--connection pool settings-->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
```

Make sure you include `hibernate-c3p0` dependency too:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```